# Remove Google Maps road highlight when using "Pegman"

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I've combined Google maps and streetview in a synchronized way, as you can see at the image below, I've also been trying to remove the "blue" road highlight on the map which shows when you use "Pegman", because these two maps are synchronized its always showing this highlight and I can't find any solution within the Google documentation [HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) or anywhere.

[Link to image](http://s15.postimg.org/hbg6wus6j/googlemaps.png)